# Why can I add a tag to one JPG file and not another in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, jpeg

On Windows 10, I grabbed two files from the Internet. One I can tag on the Details tab of the Properties window, but one I cannot (tagging is disabled). How can I make the other file taggable?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot please? Also, where exactly did you get these files?

Comment: Are both files jpeg's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information, we'll have to guess. The most likely explanation is that the untaggable image is not actually a JPEG. Tags for JPEG-format images are stored in the file itself; you can verify this by doing `type picture.jpg` in a command prompt - the comments and tags are in there. If you rename, for example, a BMP to JPG, you'll find that many fields in the Properties window are still disabled (because there's no place in the BMP format to keep that stuff).

To allow tagging, you'll need to resave the file as an actual JPEG. Most graphics editors will figure out the file's format based on its contents, so just open it up and do Save As, making sure to set the output format to JPEG.

Comment: The file extension was .jpg but "Type JPG" returned an [x]PG where x is some Eastern European letter I'm not familiar with;  I converted to jpg and its working now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my PC, and eventually found that one of the files was read only, and once I changed that I could add a tag.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and my files were neither read-only nor in a different format (all the other jpg-tags, like date, time, focal length, etc. were there, I just couldn't add new ones).
I solved the problem by rotating the pictures counter-clockwise and then back again. Just like that, I could add tags to my heart's content.